# firebase auth email link signInWithEmailLink result is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im using Next 13 with firebase, prompted user for email, sent a link to the email, when user click the link, my code calls signInWithEmailLink

```
if (isSignInWithEmailLink(auth, window.location.href)){
    console.log('is email link')
    await signInWithEmailLink(email, currentUrl).then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        console.log('yesyes')
      }
    )
    console.log('signin success')
    // Clean localStorage
    window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn')

    // Redirect user to home page
    await router.push('/')
  }
  else {
    console.log('not email link')
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error in signInAndRedirect: ', error)
}
```

However, without getting error, my result is undefined. so I'm not signed in and didn't get any error.

I checked on firebase console and didn't see user account created for the email as well. isSignInWithEmailLink returned to be true, so I believe both the email and the generated link in email are valid, so I'm running out of ideas how should i debug it.

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using localhost as domain in development and it is authorized domain on firebase console.